# Animations on hyperlink click

Tags: jquery, animation

would be possible the following animation with jquery: I have a list and each list contains 3 hyperlink and each contains a background image defined by css. If I would click on the second what is practically stays in middle on both of the sides the hyperlink should toggle out and the clicked should remain. I suppose For this I should find what are the not clicked hyperlinks from the current list. I have an example http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/78kAu/22/ what  is toggling all the ul element at this moment. and the javascript looks as it follows

```
  $('span').hover( function() {

            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1.4"}, "fast");
        },
            function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.9"}, "fast");
            });
        $('a').click(function(){
            var selected = $(this).attr('class');
            var row = $('.elements li').length;  
             $(this).closest('ul#elements').toggle('slow', function() {
                 $(this).closest('ul#elements').replaceWith('<ul id="selected"><li class="selected"><span class='+ selected + '_gray></span><h1>'+ selected + '</h1><a class="return" href="#"></a></li></ul>');    

              });        
            });
```

Comment: **WOA WOA WOA!!! back up there sonny boy...** you cannot have duplicate ID's in the same document. This is a huge nono. Use classes. I suspect the script just says "hells no" after it finds the first element with said ID... either way, **DO NOT USE DUPLICATE IDs ON THE SAME DOCUMENT!!!**

Comment: yea but now that I have "yell-typed" at you, this will be a hard lesson to forget.

Comment: Please post the relevant markup inside your question rather than linking to a jsfiddle.

Comment: anyway I'm still interested to get some useful tips